# How to change column value in a SQL database using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table, `myTable`, with a single column, `myColumn`, with a single row.

I want to change the value of `myColumn` in that first (and only) row.

I tried this, but nothing happens:

```php
$myNewValue = 'foo';
$this->db->update('myColumn', $myNewValue);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Obviously it must have something to do with not specifying which table, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote!  I found it very insightful and it showed me an entirely new approach to solve this problem from a different perspective.  Very constructive and profound feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter's update() needs to follow this [syntax](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#CI_DB_query_builder::update):

> ```
>  update([$table = ''[, $set = NULL[, $where = NULL[, $limit = NULL]]]])
>     Parameters:   
>
>         $table (string) – Table name
>         $set (array) – An associative array of field/value pairs
>         $where (string) – The WHERE clause
>         $limit (int) – The LIMIT clause
> ```

so besides of adding the correct table name, you'd need to send update data as an array, using this approach:

```
$myNewValue = array('myColumn'=>'foo');
$this->db->update('myTable', $myNewValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it:

```php
$this->db->update('myTable', [
    'myColumn' => $myNewValue,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, it is my favorite format.

```
$where = array(
       'column_id'=$id
 );
$data = array(
        'column_name'=$data
 );
$this->db->update('table_name', $data,$where);
```